# How to correctly display Cyrillic from an array of bytes in US-ASCII encoding?

Tags: java, encoding, ascii

How to correctly display Cyrillic from US-ASCII byte array?

```
`public static void main(String[] args) {
    byte[] bytes = "тестtest".getBytes(StandardCharsets.US_ASCII);
    System.out.println(getStringValue(bytes, "US-ASCII"));
}

private static String getStringValue(byte[] content, String encoding) {
    try {
        return new String(content, 0, content.length, encoding);
    } catch (UnsupportedEncodingException e) {
        return "";
    }
}`
```

output expected -> тестtest;
output actual -> ????test

Comment: `US-ASCII` does not support these characters - `getBytes()` is already returning `?` (`0x3F`) for each - `bytes = { 63, 63, 63, 63, 116, 101, 115, 116 }`

Comment: You can't US-ASCII can't represent any cyrillic characters. I.e. `bytes` has already lost all of those characters (and replaced them with the US-ASCII encoding of `?`). You can verify the numeric values in that byte array: the first 4 will have the same value 63/0x3F.